# error while" catkin_make common_msgs"

Tags: catkin, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm try to install the package : common_msgs.use wstool and catkin

i use catkin_make to make it,there is some wrong:

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(common_msgs/sensor_msgs)
-- sensor_msgs: 26 messages, 1 services
CMake Error at /home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/build/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/cmake/sensor_msgs-genmsg.cmake:191 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_description".  See documentation
  for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:288 (include)
  common_msgs/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:47 (generate_messages)


CMake Error at /home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/build/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/cmake/sensor_msgs-genmsg.cmake:376 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_description".  See documentation
  for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:288 (include)
  common_msgs/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:47 (generate_messages)


CMake Error at /home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/build/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/cmake/sensor_msgs-genmsg.cmake:561 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_description".  See documentation
  for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:288 (include)
  common_msgs/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:47 (generate_messages)
```

if you know why,plz tell me,thank u

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100036/error-while%22-catkin_make-common_msgs%22/) by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`nao_description` uses `sensor_msgs` but does not declare that dependency in its package.xml. I filled a ticket for that: https://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot/issues/17

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-11-13**:
Where does sensor_msgs actually come in? I couldn't see any reference in the CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-11-13**:
It is implicitly used in the one of the headers, @Dirk Thomas's issue links to it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically this a dependency issue. For some reason, catkin/cmake is configuring nao_description before configuring sensor_msgs.

Looking at https://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot I can't see where nao_description would be creating a dependency on sensor_msgs, so my assumption is that you have common_msgs and nao_robot in your workspace, but not tf (and nao_description depends on tf, tf depends on sensor_msgs, but you lack the cmake configuration for tf to find that dependency on sensor_msgs). My recommendation would be to do a source checkout of tf into your workspace, or stop building common_msgs in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on 2013-11-11**:
thank you very much .i install tf.and there is no errer now.thanks